# apcupsd commok event fires where there was no commfailure

Tags: ups, apc, apcupsd

I have an openSUSE Tumbleweed host connected by USB to an APC Back-UPS NS1080G.  For the most part everything works fine and `apcupsd` keeps track of the status.  But lately every few weeks it fires the `commok` event without having fired the `commfailure` event first.  When I invoke it directly `/etc/apcupsd/apccontrol` runs both my `/etc/apcupsd/commfailure` and `/etc/apcupsd/commok` scripts correctly, so I'm pretty sure my scripts aren't the problem.  `/var/log/apcupsd.events` has entries of "Communications with UPS restored" but none for lost.

What the heck is going on here?

How can I figure out what's happening with `apcupsd` that's causing this?

Comment: I have the same exact problem.  Commfailure events aren't working for apccontrol version 3.14.14-0.3 on Ubuntu.